# Função no hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, link, onclick

estou executando uma função nos hiperlinks do meu sistema, como mostra no código abaixo:

```
<md-menu-item ng-repeat="insumo in insumos">
    <a href ng-click="verificar('mostrarInsumos', insumo.ins_cl_id, '1', $event)">
        <md-button>{{insumo.ins_cl_nome}}</md-button>
    </a>
</md-menu-item>
```

Segue código da função ng-click:

```
$scope.verificar = function (ir_para, codigo, x, ev) {
    console.log("caraca mano");
    var retorno = false;
    var local = $location.url();
    console.log(local + " " + retorno);


    var subLocal = local.replace(/^\/+mostrarInsumos+\/+[0-9]{0,9}/, 'mostrarinsumos');
    console.log(subLocal);

    if (local === '/estabelecimento') {
        retorno = factoryBairro.get('estabelecimentoCtrl').verificaAlterado();
    } else if (subLocal === 'mostrarinsumos') {
        retorno = factoryBairro.get('mostrarInsumoCtrl').verificaAlterado();
        console.log(retorno);
    } else {
        retorno = false;
    }

    if (retorno === false) {
        if (x === '0') {
            $location.path(ir_para);
        } else if (x === '1') {
            factoryBairro.get('principalCtrl').sampleAction(ir_para, codigo, ev);
        }
    } else if (retorno === true) {
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
                .title('Existem dados que foram modificados, se prosseguir perderá o que foi alterado. Deseja continuar?')
                .ariaLabel('Dados Modificados')
                .targetEvent(ev)
                .ok('Sim')
                .cancel('Não');
        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            if (x === '0') {
                $location.path(ir_para);
            } else if (x === '1') {
                factoryBairro.get('principalCtrl').sampleAction(ir_para, codigo, ev);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("parece que este location não foi configurado no DashboardCtrl");
    }

};
```

Mas o problema ocorre quando é pressionado o clique da direita do mouse sobre a opção do menu, pois como o **href** esta sem nenhuma atribuição, o mesmo não abre o link que deveria ser aberto na nova aba, mas se eu atribuir a url correta ao **href** eu não vou conseguir validar se for um clique normal sobre o hiperlink, dessa forma, preciso da ajuda de vocês, agradeço desde já!

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar? :(

Comment: Poderia postar o que o "verificar" faz e como o ng-click é acionado. Existe uma solução fácil, mas que exige pelo menos o que o `verificar()` faz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

galera consegui arrumar, é só atribuir o comando

```
ev.preventDefault();
```

logo depois de criar a função verificar(), valeu pela ajuda de vocês e por terem dedicado seu tempo nesse pipino hahah abraços

Answer (score 2):

[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) faz com que o Angular intercepte o evento de click, alterando o comportamento padrão. Isso é verdade para qualquer hook via javascript.

Entretanto, mesmo o comportamento padrão muda de browser para browser. Por exemplo,

No **Chrome**,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No **Firefox**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no **Internet Explorer**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

as opções oferecidas não são completamente iguais. Se você quiser interceptar os eventos de clique-direito e o comportamento dos menus de contexto utilize um módulo angular como o [Bootstrap UI Context Menu](https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu). Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap.contextMenu']);

app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Small Health Potion', cost: 4 },
    { name: 'Small Mana Potion', cost: 5 },
    { name: 'Iron Short Sword', cost: 12 }
  ];

  $scope.menuOptions = [
    ['Buy', function ($itemScope) {
      $scope.player.gold -= $itemScope.item.cost;
    }],
    null,
    ['Sell', function ($itemScope) {
      $scope.player.gold += $itemScope.item.cost;
    }, function ($itemScope) {
      return $itemScope.item.name.match(/Iron/) == null;
    }],
    null,
    ['More...', [
      ['Alert Cost', function ($itemScope) {
        alert($itemScope.item.cost);
      }],
      ['Alert Player Gold', function ($itemScope) {
        alert($scope.player.gold);
      }]
    ]]
  ];
  $scope.otherMenuOptions = [
    ['Favorite Color', function ($itemScope, $event, color) {
      alert(color);
    }]
  ]
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='sampleApp'>
  
  
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu/master/contextMenu.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">

      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#"
           ng-repeat="item in items"
           context-menu="menuOptions">
          <span class="badge">{{item.cost}}</span>
          {{item.name}}
        </a>
      </div>      


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Infelizmene Ibotinelly, já havia feito algo pareciso, mas meu chefe solicitou que não removesse a função do navegador.

Answer (score 1):

> Nota: não sei absolutamente nada de AngularJS, nunca li sua documentação. O `ng-click` parece oferecer alguma função especifica ao Angular, mas não sei se é relevante e nada sobre isso foi mencionado.

Uma solução prática:

```js
    function verificar(e, elemento) {

      if(e === 2 || e === 3){
      // Se for clique do mouse do meio ou direito:
      
      elemento.href = 'https://google.com';

      // Somente para visualização:
      document.getElementsByTagName("ver")[0].innerHTML = 'Link atual: '+elemento.href;
     }else{
     // Se não...

     alert('Mouse esquerdo');
     }



    }
```

```html
<a href="" onmousedown="verificar(event.which, this)">
  <md-button>Clique em mim!</md-button>
</a>
<br><br>
<ver></ver>
```

A ideia é simples:

Não irá existir `HREF`, mas quando alguem clicar, com botão direito, central ou esquerdo irá ser inserido o `HREF`, então se abrir em nova aba irá ser redicionado corretamente.

Comment: Entendi Inkeliz, mas infelizmente ele não poderá aplicar o href quando clicado com o botão esquerdo do mouse, apenas quando clicar com o botão direito ou do meio ou quando pressionar control mais clique da esquerda do mouse, entende? Obrigado pela ajudar amigo